# adding new values in a typical key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

how do I add value to another dictionary to the same key like below

```
con = {'a':{'b':'c'}, b:{'d':'e'}}
```

into

```
con = {'a':{'b':'c', 'e':'f'}, b:{'d':'e'}}
```

Comment: You're example is not what you expected. Please try adding the new key-value and let us what kind of a problem you're facing.

Comment: If the unpickling if your data isn't relevant to the question (it isn't), it should be removed. Since your question is *"How do I update this dict?"*, why do you start with *"I have this pickle file..."*?

Comment: can you provide a dict that everyone can define without reworking it?

Answer (score 2):

With the current set up, its always a key and a value pair, so it will be key:value

If you would like to have more than one value to a key, please use.

```
from collections import defaultdict
myDict = defaultdict(list)
```

Now, you can add more than one value to the key.

```
myDict[key1].append(keyA:Value)
myDict[key1].append(keyB:Value)
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

With the problem as stated, there is no reason you cannot use direct key-value assignment:

```
con = {'a':{'b':'c'}, 'b':{'d':'e'}} 

con['a']['e'] = 'f'

print(con)

{'a': {'b': 'c', 'e': 'f'}, 'b': {'d': 'e'}}
```

Notice we can chain dictionary keys. This is natural because `con['a']` returns a dictionary, which can itself be assigned a new key-value pair.