# Add new VALUE to an already existent key in dictionary (Python)

Tags: python

Let

```
dict = {'key1':['key1value1'], 'key2':['key2value2']}
```

I simply want to add a new value (say key1value2) in key1, so that dict becomes:

```
dict = {'key1':['key1value1', 'key1value2'], 'key2':'key2value2'}
```

Comment: Why exactly does this need another Q&A pair? You evidently found the last one. Also note that "self" answered questions must still be a Q and A

Comment: Ok, jonrsharpe. Hi Matthias, I had mentioned the link you have provided. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most natural next step would be:

```py
dict['key1'].append('key1value2')
```

However, this .append will error if there is not currently a list, [], in place of a key's value.  In that case a more general solution would be:

```py
if key1 not in dict:
    dict['key1'] = ['key1value2']
else:
    dict['key1'].append('key1value2')
```

The 'collection.defaultdict(list)' is a merely a more elegant solution where the dictionary can always assume values are lists to be appended to but when starting, it's more important to understand these basics.

> Note: [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) can be a helpful method for similar use cases

Comment: Hi, Steven. Thanks for the nice info. (I can certainly understand the negative evaluation I got, but not yours. Well, we can live with that.)

Answer (score -4):

Solution Source:
[adding new values in a typical key in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432645/adding-new-values-in-a-typical-key-in-a-dictionary)

My Solution Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
myDict = defaultdict(list)
myDict =  {'key1':['key1value1'], 'key2':['key2value2']} 
myDict['key1'].append('key1value2')
print(myDict)
```

Comment: Hi, jonsharpe. You have posted only part of my original question/answer (without the link and credits I have given to the person who presented the solution), so that you would be able to give people the opportunity to take more point out of me? This is unethical, isn´t it? I have been a member of the Expert´s Exchange community for YEARS and it has never happened there. Never. On the contrary, the most knowledgeable people were in general, the most kind and comprehensive.

Comment: @fskilnik you seem to have posted this only so you can gain the rep for someone else's post, and *I'm* the unethical one? I made this a community wiki so I *wouldn't* benefit. And this is a different network, please use the [help] to understand what's appropriate here.

Comment: This community is extraordinary, I give you all the credit.
>>  so you can gain the rep for someone else's post,
I don´t understand all the rules here (my fault), and I also don´t know how it works, deeply. I have no intention to have rep, I am simply too ignorant to have any wishes on this matter.  But, please, let each one of us have its own beliefs. I am grateful to have my programming difficulties solved, that is really what I believe it´s the most important thing.  And I thank you for that, of course.